# Taking screenshot and converting captured text into selectable text?

Tags: windows, screenshot

In Snaggit it has a feature that let's you take a screenshot and if there are texts on screen it converts the text into selectable text (somehow) so you can copy and paste the text into a text editor for example. Is there any free software that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Docs. They allow for OCR as you upload image.

Comment: Clever! I will give it a try now!

Comment: It's not perfect. Often doesn't get everything.

Comment: @xiaodai: Perfect OCR is mythical creature - usually not found... :)

Answer (score 2):

[gocr](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) and [ocrad](http://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/) (available for at least Linux/Unix) comes to my mind.